# Manage SM Dynamic Slideshow slider effects

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

hi am using [SM Dynamic Slideshow](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sm-dynamic-slideshow-responsive-module.html) and i need to change the effects of slider. Now some random effect is coming on each slide. i need one effect for all slides. please help.

thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support. You should contact the developer for this.

Comment: i got the answer. thank you for the help..In Magento backend, go to product selection of SM Dynamic Slideshow an give all your slides the same data-easingenter preformatted text here property, e.g.: easeOutExpo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will Module specific configuration settings on the magento amdin tab see http://smartaddons.s3.amazonaws.com/images/blog/magentech/extensions/sm-dynamic-slideshow/config.jpg
I believe this is what you are looking for?
Thanks

Comment: i got the answer. thank you for the help..In Magento backend, go to product selection of SM Dynamic Slideshow an give all your slides the same data-easingenter preformatted text here property, e.g.: easeOutExpo.

Comment: Great that it worked, But the question appears to be off-toppic as quoted by @marius